# Booting windows with .bin

Tags: windows-10

Context: I am planning a new PC build. My previous PC is completely totaled and has no use. At all. The only other PC I have are some Chromebooks. So, I am building A new PC. The only problem is, I have no PC to actually download windows off of. I do some research and, I found a way to make a bootable usb drive on chrome.

Question: I am now windows expert or a generally smart person, but the recovery software I am using supports only .bin files, not the usual .iso. If I have a usb drive with a '.bin file of windows' on it, can I use it to boot into windows?

Comment: Unless you already have a Windows license I would highly suggest you purchased a license that comes with a USB drive.  Simplest solution to your problem.

Comment: I don't really have a budget to buy windows right now. I am already going to drop alot of money on new pc hardware. I was just planning on downloading the unactivated version of windows, and activating it later on when I have to money.

Comment: The simplest solution is to install a different OS, on the PC, in order to download it using a more compatible OS.  Your options are limited since there is virtually no software that exists to convert an ISO into a BIN file on Chrome OS.  Even if the software does exist it would be against the rules for anyone to recommend specific software.

Comment: But my question is, couldn't I just boot with just the .bin file? Or would I have to use an .iso file.

Comment: In order to install Windows you must boot into the installation environment.  You won't be able to create a compatible installation media with your Chromebook.

Comment: I don't think so. When you go here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO , you can install the iso file directly. I would just convert it to bin, run it in the softaware and put it on my drive.

Comment: @patrickwilliams Have you considered using a Windows or Mac computer at a public library? Also, you can go to the Microsoft Store and ask them to assist you with this. Just present proof that your previous PC had a genuine installation of Windows.

Comment: @patrickwillians - Run it what software?  You have to burn the contents of the ISO to either bootable optical media or create a bootable drive.  You can’t do either of those tasks on a Chromebook.